# Submitting a File in a POST Request With NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Similar to [Send file+parameters in post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535799/send-fileparameters-in-post-request)
 post I am trying to submit a file to an HTML form using Node.js.

I am currently trying to use the [http-post package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-post) however my code is currently executing without any errors but without submitting the form properly.

```
var http = require('http');
http.post = require('http-post');

var files = {
    param: "file",
    path: "<filepath>",
    Headers: 'update=<filename>'
};

http.get('http://192.168.84.22/update');

http.post('http://192.168.84.22/update', 'update=<filename>', files, function(res){});
```

I have captured the HTTP request that I am trying to recreate programmatically from when I have manually submitted the file:

[image: Desired HTTP Request]